# Exception handler to give error message on CMD When machine is not connected to internet

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd, exception

Coming directly to the point, I found out a **JavaScript** on Stack which gets value of any file visible over the Internet and store it, for an instance, if index.html on any site contains value "hello" it will fetch it and store it in a file or anything..

The script is-

```
var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
WinHttpReq.Open("GET", WScript.Arguments(0), /*async=*/false);
WinHttpReq.Send();
WScript.Echo(WinHttpReq.ResponseText);
```

Saving the above script as "fetch.js" and to trigger the script, making use of command "cscript" of CMD

```
cscript /nologo fetch.js "URL" > file.html
```

All works fine but when my PC is not connected to the networks, the batch terminates without giving any errors.. At last, i need some lines of codes to overcome my problem so that whenever the PC isn't connected to network, it should give out an error message or something, Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try with PING command before the script lunch.

Comment: or you can use try-catch surrounding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
try {
     var WinHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
     WinHttpReq.Open("GET", WScript.Arguments(0), /*async=*/false);
     WinHttpReq.Send();
     WScript.Echo(WinHttpReq.ResponseText);

} catch (err) {
     WScript.Echo(err.message);
     WScript.Quit(666);
}
```

or something like this when you are calling the js:

```
ping -n 1 "google.com" >nul 2>&1 || (
  echo error: no internet connection
  exit /b 666
)&&(
  cscript /nologo fetch.js "google.com" > file.html
)
```

Comment: fetch.js(7, 2) Microsoft JScript runtime error:'Wscript' is undefinedfetch.js(7, 2) Microsoft JScript runtime error:'Wscript' is undefined

Comment: @user7209422 - you should use `WScript` as it is in the code in the answer. with upper `S`

Comment: Works fine.. Thanks 

Comment: @user7209422 - now you can accept the answer and get some points for that